# Elemental Skill Damage on items

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I've got a question about the elemental skill damage. I haven't yet found an item with Elemental Skill % increase, and I can't seem to figure out if I can enchant an item with that stat. I don't know if an item must have that stat on it already for it to be changed, or can another stat (like crit hit % chance) be changed to the Elemental Skill % increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+Elemental Skill damage can't roll on every slot. The only normal items that can have elemental skill damage are bracers and amulets. There are some exceptions to this, but they are legendary items that specifically roll with elemental skill damage such as Stone of Jordan or Cindercoat.

Comment: Stone of Jordan rolls Elite damage I believe not Elemental, correct? Magefists roll +fire damage along with Cindercoats you mentioned.

Comment: So an item with 6 enchantments that are not Elemental Skill can't be rolled to Elemental Skill? I've got no other choice than to find an item with it?

Comment: @Katustrawfic It rolls both (at least on PC): http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan

Comment: @Jeff It depends on the type of item, not what is on it already. What type of item are you trying to enchant?

Comment: Ah, I saw you had said bracers and amulets. I've got a one handed weapon with 20% holy skill, and I had seen a video saying that lightning was one of the best elemental skills to go with. I didn't realize you couldn't change it on swords, so I've gone with a holy skill. I'm just not sure how to get stronger, I can survive on Torment 3 but I can never complete cursed chests in time, get through rifts quickly, etc.

Comment: If bracers or amulets don't have any elemental damage on them, you can reroll any primary affix to get elemental damage. This includes rares and all legendaries. However, only certain legendaries in other slots can roll elemental damage, which is why the cindercoat and magefist examples are given. They both will always roll fire damage.

Comment: @Jeff If you read the official forums (http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/) for your class, that might give you some ideas as to how to improve and play at harder difficulty levels.

Comment: Forgot to mark as answered. I just don't have the right kind of equipment for Torment 3, even though I can survive, I'm not yet thriving. Thanks for the help everyone!